# Appending each item in an array with multiple suffixes then make new array

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to run an array through a for loop to append the items checked onto each array with each one appending the suffix with $n (1-3). Thank you for your suggestions I am one step closer, now I am getting each suffix on one item. I want each one as its own item in the array. Can anyone see the error?

I have updated my code and it is one step closer to the solution and underneath it is what I am aiming for.

```
$equip = 'Phone';
$ailments_checkvar =  explode(', ', 'Cracked, Scratched, Bent, Twisted');

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as &$value) {
    $value = 'directory/'.$equip.'_'.$value.'';
}
unset($value);
$duplicateArray = $ailments_checkvar;

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}
for ($n = 1; $n <= 3; $n++) {

foreach ($duplicateArray as &$valueN) {
    $valueN = $valueN.'_0'.$n.'.pdf';
}
}
unset($valueN);
print_r ($duplicateArray);
```

**Getting this**

```
Array ( [0] => directory/Phone_Cracked_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[1] => directory/Phone_Scratched_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[2] => directory/Phone_Bent_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[3] => directory/Phone_Twisted_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[4] => directory/Phone_Cracked_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[5] => directory/Phone_Scratched_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[6] => directory/Phone_Bent_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[7] => directory/Phone_Twisted_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[8] => directory/Phone_Cracked_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[9] => directory/Phone_Scratched_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[10] => directory/Phone_Bent_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
[11] => directory/Phone_Twisted_01.pdf_02.pdf_03.pdf 
)
```

**And want to make this...**

```
Array ( 
[0] => directory/Phone_Cracked_01.pdf 
[1] => directory/Phone_Cracked_02.pdf 
[2] => directory/Phone_Cracked_03.pdf 
[3] => directory/Phone_Scratched_01.pdf 
[4] => directory/Phone_Scratched_02.pdf
[5] => directory/Phone_Scratched_03.pdf
[6] => directory/Phone_Bent_01.pdf 
[7] => directory/Phone_Bent_02.pdf 
[8] => directory/Phone_Bent_03.pdf 
[9] => directory/Phone_Twisted_01.pdf
[10] => directory/Phone_Twisted_02.pdf
[11] => directory/Phone_Twisted_03.pdf 
)
```

Comment: New Attempt
`$equip = 'Phone';
$ailments_checkvar =  explode(', ', 'Cracked, Scratched, Bent, Twisted');

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as &$value) {
    $value = 'wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/pdf/'.$equip.'_'.$value.'';
}
unset($value);
$duplicateArray = $ailments_checkvar;

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}

foreach ($ailments_checkvar as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}

for ($n = 1; $n <= 3; $n++) {

foreach ($duplicateArray as &$valueN) {
    $valueN = $valueN.'_0'.$n.'.pdf';
}
}
unset($valueN);
print_r ($duplicateArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this statement here,

```
$valueN = $ailments_checkvar.'_0'.$n.'.pdf';
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`$ailments_checkvar` is an array, not a string. In the above statement, you're trying to convert an array to a string. It should be,

```
$valueN = $valueN.'_0'.$n.'.pdf';
```

#### Update(1):

Based on the requirement you posted above, **the solution** would be like this:

```
$equip = 'Phone';
$ailments_checkvar =  explode(', ', 'Cracked, Scratched, Bent, Twisted');

$path_array = array();
foreach($ailments_checkvar as $property_status){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i){
        $path_array[] = 'directory/' . $equip . '_' . $property_status . '_0' . $i . '.pdf';
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r ($path_array);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/644683).

Comment: ah okay, now I understand. I have made progress and updated the question.

Comment: @JasonLauve I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: Rajdeep Paul,
Thanks for the update! I found myself making the code too complex and overlooking the `array()`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($z=1;$z<=count($ailments_checkvar);$z++) {
$ailments_checkvar[$z-1] = $ailments_checkvar[$z-1].'_0'.$z.'.pdf';
}
unset($z);
```

what ever u did was causing the stack problem for $ailments_checkvar
please check out this is optimized code.

your error lies in $valueN = *$ailments_checkvar*.'_0'.$n.'.pdf';

Comment: Thank  you very much that helped me move forward. I have made progress and updated the question.